# ReactNative Pull To Refresh for iOS platform

Tags: reactjs, animation, react-native, react-native-ios

All Dev, I am working on pull to refresh feature in my react native project. As we all know that react native itself providing a [Refresh Control](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/refreshcontrol) that we can us along with List and ScrollView but not with `View` that's fine.

I notice that there’s no common gesture for refreshing the page data for both platform if we go with the [Refresh Control](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/refreshcontrol) because of fundamental different

After reading this article[here](https://medium.com/@elye.project/android-vs-ios-pull-to-refresh-f9e7f1f6fc26):

- For iOS, the Pull-to-Refresh embedded in as part of the list.
- For Android, the Pull-to-Refresh is not part of the list, but on top
  of it.

Now my question is there any way to implement the same gesture for refreshing on iOS platform either native side or react side. For android we have `SwipeRefreshLayout` but do we have any controller that help to achieve the same gesture in iOS platform?.

Below is the refresh image from android platform:(Gmail App)

[image]

Sorry in case of you can't understand the question. feel free to comment will update. Any suggestion and comments are welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: https://github.com/sconstantinides/react-pullable

Comment: @Jean-Paul Looking Loader on top of content not along with the content.